# Windows Log github user in git

Tags: node.js, git, github, window

Anyone know a way to log my github user into Git in Windows 10 to download private dependencies from NPM (I have access to them) but I don't find out how.

I already tried with a git manager (https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/releases/tag/v1.8.0) or set a credential with git config, neither work.

Or how could I add the repo manually to global `node_module`?

Any clue how to do it? Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try with the same git credential manager, but completed with a npm library taking advantage of said credential helper.
See "[`nwinkler/git-credential-helper`](https://github.com/nwinkler/git-credential-helper)":

> Node library that allows using the Git credential API. The Git credential API allows you to store and retrieve credentials for Git hosts, preventing you from having to enter your username and password every time.
>   To use this, you have to set up your local Git client installation to make use of a credential helper

A more recent library for the same effect would be [`git-credential-node`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-credential-node) ([repo GitHub](https://github.com/parro-it/git-credential-node))

```
npm install --save git-credential-node
```

Answer (score 0):

I just has to use the command NPM into Git Bash to be able to use the SSH key.